# Is there a Qiskit function that allows you to see what qubit/quantum register said gate is attached to?

Tags: quantum-computing, qiskit

I am trying to find a way to know what named qubit/quantum register a quantum gate (i.e. labelled Pauli-X gate) would be attached to. The documentation does not have a function nor example that informs me of how to go about doing this. The picture below outlines that I am trying to find qubit n0 from quantum gate U0.

[Example quantum circuit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6yRo.png)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this would probably be to access the [`data` attribute](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.data) of your `QuantumCircuit` object (e.g. `circuit.data` if your circuit object is named `circuit`). This will be a list of tuples with the instruction objects (ie the gate instance), the quantum bit arguments for that instruction, and the classical bit arguments for the instruction: `(instruction, qargs, cargs)`. For your example circuit it is simple because there is one only one gate so it'll be the first element in that list. So for that case you can do something like `u0_qubits = circuit.data[0][1]` and `u0_qubits` will be a list of the `Qubit` objects. Trying to do this for larger circuits with possible duplicate gates will obviously be more involved.